# Can how could I import java dependency with symbol group id "-"?

Tags: java, import

Can I know how could i import a dependency with "-" example:
https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/affinity-project/
https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/ai-flow/

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ai-flow</groupId>
            <artifactId>aiflow-parent</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.affinity-project</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-check-widget-backend-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Using import as below are not allowed:

```
import org.affinity-project.
import org.ai-flow.
```

Comment: Inspect the jars or read the javadocs, seems the package is `org.aiflow`

Comment: You are confusing Maven groupIds with Java package names.  The groupId is not something you import.